# Get list of differences between contour and its convex hull

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I use OpenCV to write a small app for counting parameters of specific details.

The point is that because the detail glints I cannot get it's precise contour. It is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkr78.jpg). As you can see, the center of detail is white so the result contour looks like a horseshoe.

Also I cannot use convex hull to wrap the gained contour cause i'll lose accuracy which counts in my situation.

In my mind I already have the solution of this issue. The idea is to:

1. Get convex hull of the detail's contour
2. Subtract area of contour from the area of hull and get list of polygons that are contained by hull, but not by detail's contour
3. Choose the biggest of such polygons and add it to the contour

One thing I still cannot figure out is if there any way to get difference between areas in the form I need it with OpenCV?

Any help appreciated

Comment: This is a convex object. Why would you lose accuracy with the convex hull?

Comment: Ok, maybe this example is not the best.
Detail's edge is not ideal an in fact it is broken line. When I get convex hull it smooths all the flaws. When i then count volume of the detail (as rotational integral of contour) it makes great sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I implemented my own solution. It works quite well for my needs, but method of subtraction one shape from another there is suitable only for subtraction contour from its convex hull.

```
import numpy
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from config.config import Config
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

cfg = Config.get_config(None)

def __cure_detail_contour(self, contour):
    # processes the contour and its convex hull and gives back contour without light notch

    contour_hull = cv2.convexHull(contour)

    # find product of subtraction contour from its convex hull
    subtraction_polygons = []
    previous_polygon = []
    for contour_point in contour:
        previous_polygon.append([[contour_point[0][0], contour_point[0][1]]])
        if cv2.pointPolygonTest(contour_hull, (contour_point[0][0], contour_point[0][1]), False) == 0:
            if len(previous_polygon) > 2:
                subtraction_polygons.append(previous_polygon)
            previous_polygon = [[[contour_point[0][0], contour_point[0][1]]]]

    # in the list of subtracted polygons find one with maximum area. Consider this one to be the notch
    max_flaw_area = 0
    max_area_polygon = None

    for sub_contour in subtraction_polygons:
        cv_contour = numpy.array(sub_contour)
        area = cv2.contourArea(cv_contour)

        if area > max_flaw_area:
            max_flaw_area = area
            max_area_polygon = sub_contour

    # checking ratio of contour area to the maximal flaw error to avoid
    # smoothing edge flaws (to avoid losing preciseness)
    contour_area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if max_flaw_area < cfg.cure_flaw_min_area_coeff * contour_area:
        return contour

    polygon = Polygon([[p[0][0], p[0][1]] for p in max_area_polygon])
    contour_polygon = Polygon([[p[0][0], p[0][1]] for p in contour])

    result_contour = cascaded_union([polygon, contour_polygon])

    # x, y = polygon.exterior.xy
    # plt.plot(x, y, "bo")
    # plt.show()
    #
    # x, y = contour_polygon.exterior.xy
    # plt.plot(x, y, "g")
    # plt.show()

    x, y = result_contour.exterior.xy
    # plt.plot(x, y, "r")
    # plt.show()

    contour = numpy.array([ [[numpy.int32(x[i]), numpy.int32(y[i])]] for i in range(min(len(x), len(y)))])

    return contour
```